# Flutter is not finding android sdk

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

Whenever i run flutter doctor the following error comes

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 
10.0.22000.438], locale en-IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
 X Android SDK file not found: C:\Users\rehan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\32.1.0-rc1\aapt.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

 ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.


I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling android studio, and 
 adding platform and platform tools to the system environment path
```

The below i have added the photo of cmd
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoK8I.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can try this:

`flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-your-android-sdk>`

2. Also you can add the sdk path to Environment variables.
   --> Open system properties
   --> Environment variables
   --> create new system variable
   --> name: ANDROID_HOME
   --> value:  your SDK path
   --> close your current cmd, and restart it
   --> run flutter doctor
3. Another one you can try to check the path to your sdk (`C:\Users\rehan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\32.1.0-rc1\aapt`) And if the folder in `C:\...\build-tools\` don't contain aapt.exe deleting this folder. Restart cmd and try the doctor again.

Comment: For me it worked by deleting the build-tools folder and reinstalling the build sdk folder from sdk manager but thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and Deleting my build tool and installing through android studio works for me